# How do I align text boxes under each other in CSS/HTML

Tags: css, html

I want to know how to place these textboxes under another so `.textbox` is at the top and then `textbox1` is below.

CSS

```
.textbox { 
    border: 1px solid #848484; 
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #848484;
    outline:0; 
    height:25px; 
    width: 275px; 
    padding-left:20px; 
    padding-right:20px;
} 

.textbox1 { 
    border: 1px dotted #000000; 
    outline:0; 
    height:25px; 
    width: 275px; 
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="textbox" type="text"> 
<input class="textbox1" type="text">
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest adding:

```
input {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5V4Z8/).

The `display: block` forces each of the `input` elements to fully occupy its own 'line', whereas the `box-sizing` forces the browser to include the `border-width` and `padding` in the calculation of the width of the element (so that their widths match).

References:

- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like:

```
input[type=text] {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```

should be sufficient enough

http://jsfiddle.net/cFPBZ/

Answer (score 0):

how about adding this one line to css:

```
.textbox{display:block;}
```

while adding `class="textbox"` to all textboxes.

hope that helps.